ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' in VSCode
I am trying to learn pandas, numpy, and matplotlib but vscode cannot find the module when I import them and run the code.enter image description here
I tried checking if I have downloaded it with cmd and they showed up. enter image description here
Can anyone help? Thanks and appreciate it!

The "enter image description" is a placeholder where you are supposed to enter a description. Please don't use images of text though, use the actual text (properly formatted) instead.

In VSCode, you should chose which version of Python will get used from the status bar at the bottom right. In the terminal, activate your conda environment like @ryyyn says in their answer.

Sorry for the inconvenience, this is my first time posting a question. Thanks for the advice!

In your first screenshot, you are running your code using a system installation of Python. In your second screenshot, you are using an Anaconda virtual environment. (A virtual environment is essentially a separate installation of Python packages. This is useful if you download different Python code which depends on different versions of the same package.)
You can tell that a virtual environment is activated because of the text in parentheses (base) before the prompt. (Also, note that the versions of Python are different.)
You can either run your code from the command line with the activated base environment, or install the pandas/numpy/matplotlib libraries system-wide by running pip install pandas etc. in Command Prompt.
